# Checking value of returned JSON and updating if false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that fetches questions from an external API. I need to have at least 5 questions in a array for my application to function.

```
function getCategoryQuestions(){
  var questions = {};
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < 6; i++){
    $.getJSON(makeURL(), function(data){
      data = data.category;
      questions[data.name] = data.questions;
      validQuestionsLength(questions, data.questions)
    })

  }
  return questions;
}
```

I run validQuestionsLength to check if each questions array is at least 5 elements in length.

```
function validQuestionsLength(hash, array){
  while (array.length < 5) {
    $.getJSON(makeURL(), function(data){
      data = data.category;
      hash[data.name] = data.questions
      array = data.questions;
    })
    console.log(array.length)
  }
}
```

I want to check if an array's length is less than 5 and if so I'll fetch a new resource from the url. I'll save the new value to array and then it will check this new value's array length. I want it to keep fetching data until the condition is true.

What's happening is that once the validQuestionsLength() method runs and I have an array length with less than 5, it keeps console.logging the current array in an infinite loop. I thought I was saving a new resource to array on each loop.

I'm not sure where my logic error is happening.

I know there is an asynchronous request occurring so the console.log may run before the array variable is reset. I edited my validation function to include a done callback to execute once the async has finished

```
function validQuestionsLength(hash, array){

  if (array.length < 5) {
    $.getJSON(makeURL(), function(data){
      data = data.category;
      hash[data.name] = data.questions

      console.log("data is ", data.questions)
      array = data.questions;
    }).done(console.log("array is ", array ))
  }
}
```

My intention was to to save the newly fetched data to array. But data.questions and the array (that should point to the value for data.questions) are different values. What is .done() doing in this case?

Comment: So is your call returning one question at a time or N?  Are you looking for five per data.name or five total across all data.name entires?  Right now the way you have it array is being overwritten with each call so unless your api call is returning five items you will loop forever.

Comment: Use `array.push(data.questions)` instead of `array = data.questions;` I am not aware of your Json structure you might need to add some index there like `questions[0]` or something

Comment: You're setting done callback function wrong, you need to embed the code in lambda function as for success callback, now you're settings result of console.log as the callback of **done** event. So it is executed now still before callback.

Comment: Your while loop also is not right. You cannot loop getJSON because you will run many request before callback even execute for first request made. You need to rethink the whole process and make function call itself in callback or something.

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you want to end up with. Could you please add one or more examples of `questions` that meet the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit2**: I made example how your two functions may look as valid callback loop, both functions are similar so it can be just one function:

> I have simplified my script and for tests I made my testResponse php script returns 4 elements ["1", "2", "3", "4"] array few times and finally it returns 5 elements ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] array.

```
function getCategoryQuestions(callback){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/testResponse.php', function(data){              
        if(data.questions.length < 5){
            getCategoryQuestions(callback);
        } else {                    
            callback(data.questions);
        }
    });
}
```

The code will get json from url, if the questions array is less then 5 it will request the url again until there will be 5 or more questions in array.

If there will be 5 or more questions in array it won't execute itself again, it will call callback with questions array as an argument.

This is how you use the function and receiver your questions array:

```
getCategoryQuestions(function(questions){
    console.log(questions);
});
```

There is more to be done, like ajax error handling.

**Edit:** getJSON is async funciton so it will call its callback function after it will fetch the data, so the callback will be executed later anyway, even if it is not added to event queue.

It is because getJSON success callback function execution is added to event queue, and it executes after you console.log your array.length

I made a test:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.getJSON('http://localhost/testResponse.php', function(data){
                console.log('Callback');
            });
            console.log('Script end');
        </script>
        Hello!
    </body>
</html>
```

And the result in console is:

```
Script end
Callback
```

To explain further how it happens I will provide two examples
1st example:

```js
function callCallback(callback){
 callback();
}

callCallback(function(){
 console.log('Callback');
});
console.log('Script end');
```

Will produce:

```
Callback
Script end
```

And the second one:

```js
function callCallback(callback){
 setTimeout(callback, 0);
}

callCallback(function(){
 console.log('Callback');
});
console.log('Script end');
```

Output will be same as my getJSON example, so:

```
Script end
Callback
```

It is because even thare is zero timeout, callback function is added to event queue, so it is not executed immediately.

**Edit:** Also getJSON is async funciton so it will call its callback function after it will fetch the data, so the callback will be executed later anyway, even if it is not added to event queue.